# Why does the Firebase childEventListener not work with one reference while it works with the other?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, event-listener

The references are:

```java
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
```

```java
DatabaseReference TUidRef = usersRef.child(td);
```

The value of `td` is derived as follows from previous activity to this:

```java
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

        final String dataName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        usersdRef.orderByChild("username").equalTo(dataName).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    String dataUID = data.child("uid").getValue(String.class);
                    Log.i("uid",dataUID);
                    startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main5Activity.class).putExtra("valueName", dataName).putExtra("valueUID",dataUID));

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });


    }
});
```

```java
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
td = bundle.getString("valueUID");
```

The `childEventListener` works with `usersRef` but not with the `TUidRef` and it does not crashes or anything, it just doesn't do anything.

The database looks something like this:
[image: database]

Comment: u should pass the value to the other activity and then receive it `intent.putExtra("valueUID",dataUID);`

Comment: @PeterHaddad I have passed the value using `putExtra()`, and showed the code for receiving the value, but the listener is not working. I don't know why.

Comment: I answered a *very* similar question yesterday. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52116824/why-is-the-childeventlistener-not-working/52117264#52117264. If that question was from you but my answer wasn't clear, comment on that question. If that question wasn't from you, it's pretty certainly a duplicate.

Comment: @PradyumanDixit oh didnt see it, my bad

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I don't know about that question, but can you tell me the reason why `childEventListener` does not work.

Comment: The reason is *exactly the same* as for the question I linked. I wrote an answer with the code you need. Note that you didn't show a child listener, so I can't help with why that doesn't work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three cases:

1. When you load `/users` with a `ValueEventListener`, the `DataSnapshot` you get in `onDataChange` contains a list of users. So you need to loop over `dataSnapshot.getChildren()` to get each individual users.
2. When you **query** `/users`, there may be multiple child nodes that match the query conditions. So there too the `DataSnapshot` you get in `onDataChange` contains a list of users and you'll need to loop over them.
3. When you attach a `ValueEventListener` to `/users/$uid`, the `DataSnapshot` you get in `onDataChange` contains the properties of a single user. So you no longer need to loop over `DataSnapshot.getChildren()`:

The code for this last case:

```
TUidRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String dataUID = data.child("uid").getValue(String.class);
        Log.i("uid",dataUID);
        startActivity(new Intent(Main2Activity.this, Main5Activity.class).putExtra("valueName", dataName).putExtra("valueUID",dataUID));
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you pass the bundle correctly try to change

```
td = bundle.getString("valueUID");
```

to

```
td = getIntent().getString("valueUID");
```

Comment: I recorded the value, it is same as intended. There is no problem with passing the value.